# Facebook SDK with deactivated Facebook Developer Account

Tags: ios, facebook

I have a Facebook developer account separate from my personal account. I use the SDK to do a FB OAuth login with Firebase for an iPhone app and I use it for other apps as well. I use the app page to advertise and I just had my account put on hold where FB made me submit a pic so they can verify or whatever. I can't login to my developer account at all. I can currently still login to the app but if Facebook closes the account will I have to redo everything in the info.plist and make a new developer account?

Comment: File a bug at developers.facebook.com/bugs and have them move your apps to your real account

Comment: I filed an inquiry to Facebook already. Would you mind telling me what the response time might be? @WizKid

Comment: when I try to submit the bug I am getting: App must contain a valid Facebook app. I am using the appID directly from the info.plist. @WizKid

Comment: You must select one of the apps that your users owns. Just use anyone

Comment: I can't advance. There's nothing to select, just a text field. saying the same thing. I'm logged in to my personal account. Obviously I am not logged in to my developer account because...I can't.

Comment: Create an app on your personal account and select it

Comment: got it. Thank You @WizKid

Comment: Well suddenly I can login to my page, no email notifying me of this BTW, but I can't comment or act as the page.

Comment: They closed the bug and just said that it is a site issue, not a developer issue. My account got off of review and immediately put back under review as soon as I tried to comment as my page.